# Accessing Class Object before initializing in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a class named ItemsAdapter where I have three arguments and I am instantiating this class in another class named ItemsActivity.While doing so, I need to put up all the three arguments and the last argument is where I am gonna pass a method known as getImages() which is in the same class ItemsAdapter. I can access this only by using the ItemsAdapter object but it's not feasible. This is what I have tried :

**CODE :**

```
ItemsAdapter mAdapter = null;
ArrayList<String> image_items = mAdapter.getImages(); 
mAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(this,R.layout.item,image_items);
```

**UPDATE :**

```
public ArrayList<String> getImages()
    {
        String path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures/SanPics2/";
        File mainfolder = new File(path);
        ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(mainfolder.listFiles() == null)
        return null;
        for(File f : mainfolder.listFiles())
        {
            if(f.getName().contains(".jpg"))
            {
                files.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
        return files;
    }
```

This is the method which I am trying to access.
It throws NullPointerException as predicted. Is there a another way around this where I can access the method getImages() in ItemsAdapter class. Apologies if the question is dumb(i know it is) but I am just a beginner to programming and stuffs. Any idea on how to achieve this would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why your adapter holds that getImages call? What is its purpose?

Comment: where is `getImages`?. What does it return?

Comment: @Raghunandan getImages() returns the list of images present at a certain location in SDCard and it is in the ItemsAdapter class.

Comment: Adapter should be initialize before use. its not initialized

Comment: `getImages()` can't be called on null object. Either make that method static..

Comment: @San post adapter code

Comment: ImageAdapter can determine the images itself, no need to put them into the constructor.

Comment: still I can not understand why you need that snippet inside the Adapter and call it from the Activity

Comment: @blackbelt I am using two list views which is synced and I need to retrieve the images from my SDCard and thats the reason why I have called.

Comment: the question was different. Why did you put it inside the Adapter subclass

Comment: and don't hardcode the path for pictures... you can use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Make method as static and call it with class name***

```
public static ArrayList<String> getImages()
    {
        String path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures/SanPics2/";
        File mainfolder = new File(path);
        ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(mainfolder.listFiles() == null)
        return null;
        for(File f : mainfolder.listFiles())
        {
            if(f.getName().contains(".jpg"))
            {
                files.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
        return files;
    }
```

***And now call as***

```
ArrayList<String> image_items = ItemsAdapter.getImages();
```

---

*Better use is, to move this method into same Activity class `ItemsActivity` (if there is no other classes call this method). So put this code into `ItemsActivity` without making static*, like

```
private ArrayList<String> getImages() {....} // Same as you posted into question, but public changed to private.
```

And call this method into same Activity `ItemsActivity` as

```
mAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(this,R.layout.item, getImages());
```

Comment: Thank you so much. A simple and neat answer. Deserves a vote up and tick.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you have this code in `Activtiy` rather than adapter class.

```
public ArrayList<String> getImages()
    {
        String path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures/SanPics2/";
        File mainfolder = new File(path);
        ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(mainfolder.listFiles() == null)
        return null;
        for(File f : mainfolder.listFiles())
        {
            if(f.getName().contains(".jpg"))
            {
                files.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
        return files;
    }
```

Also use appropriate constructor as suggested by blackbelt

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html

```
public File (String dirPath, String name)

Added in API level 1
Constructs a new File using the specified directory path and file name, placing a path separator between the two.

Parameters
dirPath the path to the directory where the file is stored.
name    the file's name.
Throws
NullPointerException    if name == null.
```

Then

```
ArrayList<String> image_items = getImages();
```

Then

```
ItemsAdapter mAdapter = null;
mAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(this,R.layout.item,image_items); 
// pass the list to the constructor of adapter class and use it there
```

Comment: he should use the constructor with two parameters of File instead. In turns that constructor makes use of File.Separator

Comment: @Raghunandan That did not work. It would throw NullPointerException.

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks for your effort but I have accepted an answer and thats the most simple answer to it.

Comment: @San good for you. But this method also works provided you do it right.

Comment: @Raghunandan I am just curious and wanna know. I have placed the getImages() in the same activity where I am instantiating ItemsAdapter then why would I require the ItemsAdapter object to access that method. I have tried the following and it works like a charm. ArrayList<String> image_items = getImages() is what I have done. I dont understand why you have given as ArrayList<String> image_items = mAdapter.getImages() which would simply wouldn't work if the getImages() is in same class. I request you to edit your answer.

Comment: @Raghunandan And thanks for the suggestion of placing the getImages() in the same class. That was an easy answer if there is no problem in shifting the method.

Comment: @San there is no problem in shiftig method. In your case You already have `getImages` in adapter class. SO why make it static and again pass it to the constructor?

Comment: @Raghunandan So you're suggesting that I should use two parameters as path and file name in File instead of one and that would solve the issue ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44769/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-san)

Comment: @San join chat @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44769/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-san

Answer (score 0):

Why not Change your constructor and add a setMethod for the images if you have to draw the images from adapter? Like this?

```
ItemsAdapter mAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(this,R.layout.item);
ArrayList<String> image_items = mAdapter.getImages(); 
mAdapter.setImages(image_items);
```

or just do that work while instantiating the adapter? Much more ellegant approach

```
public ItemsAdapter(Context context, int layout) {
   //some super call
   //some work
   this.images = getImages();
}
```

Comment: So the getter puts it into the setter? Looks weird. Just use the getter inside the adapter should do here.

Comment: yes it does, i would just do all that in the adapter itself. just working with what i got :)